# How to come from 二百五 to 二百九?

Tags: meaning

I know 二百五 stands for foolish/stupid and I assume I have to add up 二百五, 三八 and 二 to it to obtain 二百九. Is this right and if so, what does 二 mean and where did it get it's meaning?

Comment: You're right. 二 is an internet slang in China, means *stupid*. But 三八 is not only "stupid", it also describes "a person who is like talking gossip (especially refer to a woman)".

Comment: 二 is just short for 二百五; that's all there is to it.

Comment: @congusbongus I believe it's short for `二逼` (as ***it's an offensive word***, the short form 二 will sound a little better by avoiding the profanity character "逼/屄").

Comment: Doesn't seem to be internet slang... It is a slang in Northern China, then spread on the internet by those students who study in PK...

Comment: @user58955 二逼 and 二百五 are definitely not internet slang. I mean the simplified form 二 may evolve during the Internet age. Like "给力", it originates from dialect, but its Chinglish form "geliable" would be better to be considered as internet slang.

Comment: @user58955 Hmm, these examples would be more proper. `哎呦妈呀` => `艾玛`; `语文老师死得早` => `语死早`; `挽救尊严` => `挽尊`. These short forms are usually considered as internet slang.

Comment: that is my point, 二 is not an internet slang -- it has been slang in Northern China...

Comment: First, I _think_ 二逼 is 二 + 逼 where 二 is short for 二百五. So still everything started with 二百五. Second, 二百五 is not the stupidity as intellectually handicapped, instead, it's 'lack of judgement, unable to grasp the situation', e.g. someone who always brings up topics at an inappropriate time, or someone who tries to be smart and gets opposite results.

Comment: Hi susis, what does "I have to add up 三八 and 二 to it to obtain 二百九", I don't understand what this means. I don't see how you are comparing 三八 to 二百九?

Comment: @xiaohouzi79 Ups, I forgot "二百五". It should be: 二百五+三八+二=二百九. It's corrected now.

Comment: What does 二百九 stand for? And why do you need to perform arithmetic to a slang in the first place? Your edit doesn't make this question any clearer.

Comment: @susisstrolch People are asking where did you see/hear 二百九 at the first place, which can help us help you find the answer. As a native speaker and active internet user I have never heard of it.

Comment: @NS.X. You can find 二百五 often on the net, e.g. http://wenwen.soso.com/z/q214772587.htm, http://zhidao.baidu.com/link?url=Yewfdwh1py3gZttO5LplfZBP6GIk6b08GTvRhI-PHkMDJEGJsGAgwXRTUxdezgJ7wrD4O_QPK81CFmjUdiPZEq, http://www.juexiang.com/gexing/0535/1071383.html, and here http://zhidao.baidu.com/link?url=Yewfdwh1py3gZttO5LplfZBP6GIk6b08GTvRhI-PHkMDJEGJsGAgwXRTUxdezgJ7wrD4O_QPK81CFmjUdiPZEq

Comment: Are you serious for asking 290? Isn't it a joke?

Answer (score 6):

## 三八

Comes from "March" (3, 三) "Eighth" (8, 八):

KEY:

> March Eighth (International Working Women's Day)

and then evolved into what it means today (stupid, foolish, batty, gossipy, bitchy). It has no relation to 二百五.

## 二百五

规范

> 过去银子五百两为一封, 二百五十两为半封, 谐音“半疯”。借指带有傻气、做事鲁莽的人。

Basically 250 = 半封 which sounds like 半疯 or half-crazy.

## 二

百度知道

> 1. “二”是河南一带的方言俚语，其来源是“二蛋”简称，“二蛋”的同义语有“二球”、“二杆子”、“二性（这里的“性”读轻声）”，意思均指某人鲁莽爱拼命，或指稍微冒犯即给对方以极不相称的极不必要的数十倍的攻击。一般人们通常会说，“这个人‘二’的很，别惹他”；“那家伙真‘二’，就说他一句掂砖头朝头上砸过去了”。
>      河南方言形容这类行为的说法是“脑子一热，不顾一切”（用河南话念，很押韵合辙）。
>
>    我再补充一点，三楼的第二点：“应该是做形容词用。 比如东北常说，你咋那么“二”呢！等等
>      ”之意思正是“二蛋”之意，你咋那么“二”呢！是避讳不雅字眼，完整的应该说“你咋那么二蛋（或二球、二性、二杆子）呢！”也就是出傻气的意思。
>
>    “二性”用来描述人时有时候也可重叠，作“二二性性”，如“那家伙二二性性的，别理他，别跟他一般见识。”
>
>    “二”以及它的那些全称词组还有引申义，指某人说话缺乏考虑，口无遮拦，胡扯八道，或满嘴脏话（不分场合的讲脏话），此时有一个专门的词叫“二驣（音”teng，第三声），属于“专有名词”，专用来指说话。如：那家伙是个二驣，说话没边，云天雾地的（这个意思时还有个专门的比喻词叫“老鸹屁”）。再如：她真是个二驣，跟一帮男的说话屌啊屌的，不像个女的。
>
>    2.　　2据说是原来人们称呼的250的简称。人们后来觉得叫人家250有些直接了当的辱骂，显得自己多么不文明，没素质，就简化成2了。
>
>    二百五的来历
>
>    二百五的来历日常生活中，人们常把傻瓜或说话不正经、办事不认真、处事随便、好出洋相的人叫做“二百五”。
>
>    一说来源于战国故事。苏秦是战国时的一个说客，他身佩六国相印，一时很是威风，但也结下了很多仇人。后来，他终于在齐国被人杀了，齐王很恼怒，要为苏秦报仇。可一时拿不到凶手，于是，他想了一条计策，让人把苏泰的头从尸体上割下来，悬挂在城门上，旁边贴着一道榜文说：“苏秦是个内*，杀了他黄金千两，望来领赏。”榜文一贴出，就有四个人声称是自己杀了苏秦。齐王说：“这可不许冒充呀！”四个人又都咬定说自己干的。齐王说：“一千两黄金，你们四个人各分得多少？”四个齐声回答：“一人二百五。”齐王拍案大怒道：“来人，把这四个‘二百五’推出去斩了！”“二百五”一词就这样流传下来。
>
>    还有另一种说法，与推牌九有点关系。
>
>    原来，牌九（旧时一种赌具）中有“二板”（四个点）和“么五”（六个点）两张牌，这两张牌配在一起就是十个点，在推牌九这一赌博活动中，被称为“毙十”。它在牌九里是最小的点，谁都比它大，它什么牌也“吃”不了，所以人们就用“二板五”（二板和么五的简称）这个词来戏称什么事也做不好也管不了的人。时间久了，就把“二板五”叫成了“二百五”。在香港，习惯上又称为“二五仔”。
>
>    a:东北方言，常用于形容人或事物愚笨，口语中拥有独特的语意。
>
>    b:陕西方言，常用于形容一个人分不清场合，掂不来轻重，说话不过大脑，做事不想后果。如“二怂，二锤子”。例，那个人二得很！
>      或形容自己听到惊人且不能理解的言论时的心理状况，如“我二了”。
>
>    c:天津方言，贬意词。常用用于形容人愚笨，弱智的意思。现在多用于彼此取笑的意思（有很大的玩笑成分）。

tl;dr: or don't understand chinese:
1. came from topolect
2. shortening of 250

Comment: +1. Quite comprehensive.

Answer (score 3):

We Chinese don't say "二百九" but just "二百五" to describe someone is foolish, a typical example is:

你这个二百五，办事没有一件可以办好！

Besides we also have "二货"、“二B（Chinese character：屄；Chinese pronuncation: bi）”，This is a offensive saying that is always used to abuse others when you are angry or despise others (very very dirty!), so PLEASE DON'T USE THAT.

"二" can be also used traditionally in the north dialect of China, meaning "foolish". It can be used as an adjective word——e.g:

你真二！

Answer (score 0):

二  is the simple Chinese ,it is the same meaning as 贰 in traditional Chinese,贰 means rebel,so 二 is a bad word in Chinese.